# Android building no rule to make lib

Tags: android, android-build

I'm currently building the dirty unicorn ROM for my Xperia V and when running brunch tsubasa it build for about 3 minutes and then return this error:

make: *** No rule to make target `/home/pavle/android/dirty/out/target/product/tsubasa/obj/lib/libtime_genoff.so', needed by`/home/pavle/android/dirty/out/target/product/tsubasa/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_runtime.so'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

I did check and find that there is a rule to use that lib in a file called tsubasa-vendor-blobs.mk:

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \ 
...
    vendor/sony/tsubasa/proprietary/lib/libtime_genoff.so:system/lib/libtime_genoff.so \
...

I think that the build process wants to build that file and not use the prebuilt, but I don't know where I can add a rule for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some solutions for that issue:

- Track, if you don't, your device proprietary blobs from TheMuppets, ThankYouMario, DonkeyCoyote or any of the rest that are available.
- Extract your own device blobs
- Copy directly to /home/pavle/android/dirty/out/target/product/tsubasa/obj/lib/ the required file

See you!